# How to set max_execution_time during mysqldump

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to take a backup of my database in a CI before database schema change are made and for local development.  However recently we ran into an issue where some tables are to large to dump, we get the following error:

> mysqldump: Error 3024: Query execution was interrupted, maximum
> statement execution time exceeded when dumping table `social_post` at
> row: 24988140

After investigating i found that if i modify the `max_execution_time` from 600000 (10 mins) to 0 (unlimited). The backup works, it takes approx 1 hour and 10 mins to get make a full backup. (we tried 15 minutes and even 20 minutes and it was not enough)

We don't want to permanently set this value to unlimited because of possible consequences, we'd like to just change it for the duration of the mysqldump.

Is there some way to set `max_execution_time` for mysqldump.

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=login.cnf --set-gtid-purged=OFF --single-transaction --events --routines --no-create-info --no-create-db --skip-triggers --complete-insert --verbose --quick database_name > data.sql
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: does this help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223798/mysql-set-variable-in-mysqldump

Comment: @IvoP I saw that, `max_execution_time` or `max_statement_time` is not a variable you set can set within the .cnf file under [mysqldump]. So unfortunately it does not help,.

Comment: but is does show an option to add this to a backup.cnf file so it would not affect other queries

Comment: @IvoP it does not matter what you name the .cnf file its an input to --defaults-file/defualts-extra-file, theres even a comment on that answer which says exactly the same as what i just said...

Comment: Set the variable in the `[client]` section of your backup .cnf file. Mysqldump reads that section.

Comment: @BillKarwin I know mysqldump reads [mysqldump] are you suggesting i can put `max_execution_time` under [client] and it will read that? can you point me to any documentation mentioning that?

Comment: "_mysqldump supports the following options, which can be specified on the command line or in the `[mysqldump]` and `[client]` groups of an option file._" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html -- It's in the manual page you linked to yourself!

Comment: Another reference: "_a `[client]` group is more general because it is read by all client programs, whereas a `[mysqldump]` group is read only by mysqldump. Options specified later override options specified earlier, so putting the option groups in the order `[client]`, `[mysqldump]` enables mysqldump-specific options to override `[client]` options._" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: @BillKarwin `[client]
max_execution_time=0` `mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'max_execution_time=0'.`

Comment: This shows that max_execution_time can only be set as a server option. Frankly, I never restrict the max_execution_time globally. I understand the desire to avoid runaway queries, but setting a global limit on _all_ queries has even more unwanted consequences.

Comment: You can set max_execution_time for a specific session with SET SESSION. I am still worried about consequences of setting max_execution_time 0 all the time, on aws rds it is restricted by default, im guessing for a good reason.